# C# JSON Spanish is UTF8 but German is UTF7 to load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a website that is to have specific languages setup.  All pages and their text are in one JSON per language.   I'm using the browser Server Variable to tell what language is if we have the JSON conversion for it, we display the text in their language.  Default is English if we don't cover it.

However, we load the data with the following code and it works for English and Spanish.

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(JSONFilePath);
string someString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
RecordData = (DataSet)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(someString, (typeof(DataSet)));
```

However, we noticed it doesn't work for German.  We found that we have to use UTF7 for German.

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(JSONFilePath);
string someString = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(bytes);
RecordData = (DataSet)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(someString, (typeof(DataSet)));
```

If we use UTF8 for German, we get symbols, in some characters.  If use UTF7 for Spanish the same thing will happen.  We are setting up 10 or so languages, so how do we know which to encode the data with before we deserialize it?

Comment: [What encoding](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) are the json files using? Remove the `GetString` line, change the `ReadAllBytes` to `ReadAllText` and [provide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) that encoding.

Comment: Being created by Visual Studio 2019.  So they will all be UTF-8, but rather I have to read them in under the correct encoding or save them under the correct encoding, I need to know how to know which language uses which encoding.

Comment: Please visit the first link from above. All languages can use UTF-8. If at some point you are resaving the file with a different encoding, then you should stop doing that. Languages do not use encodings. Files do. If you want to make your life much harder for absolutely no reason, then yes, you can nominate a separate encoding for each file, but then only you will know which encoding maps to which file, so maintain that list manually on your side. UTF-8 is a correct encoding for any language.

Comment: Weird. It's supposed to redirect to https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/.

Comment: I went back and saved as UTF-8 (no signature) and it's working.  I guess somehow the files were saved as something else, but were all created by VS 2019.

Comment: Add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to encode files for different languages in different code pages. You can, but you will only make your life harder for no good reason. You will need to maintain the mapping between your codepages of choice and your files yourself.

[Unicode](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) covers all languages. UTF-8 supports all of Unicode, as do all Unicode encodings.

Make sure you always save all your files as UTF-8, and make sure you always provide an encoding when reading from these files, at which point your code should be:

```cs
string someString = File.ReadAllText(JSONFilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
RecordData = (DataSet)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(someString, (typeof(DataSet)));
```

Comment: I found the default, which I never knew, is created by Visual Studio 2019 as Western European (Windows).  Seems a bit odd, instead of picking something more generic like UTF-8, which covers a the Western European as well as many others.